# DynamoDB batchWrite, different hash key, same range key. but got Provided list of item keys contains duplicates

Tags: database, go, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I got table key schema like this:

```
        KeySchema: []*dynamodb.KeySchemaElement{{
                AttributeName: aws.String("address"),
                KeyType:       aws.String(dynamodb.KeyTypeHash),
            }, {
                AttributeName: aws.String("tx_id"),
                KeyType:       aws.String(dynamodb.KeyTypeRange),
            }},
```

write record like this:

```
    for _, storeKey := range t.StoreKeys() {
        mainItem["address"], err = dynamodbattribute.Marshal(storeKey)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        mainTxPut := dynamodb.PutRequest{
            Item: mainItem,
        }

        writeRequests = append(writeRequests, &dynamodb.WriteRequest{
            PutRequest: &mainTxPut,
        })
    }
```

but when using different address value, same tx_id, i got err:
ValidationException: Provided list of item keys contains duplicates

Beacuese hashkey is different, i should be using a different key. So why dynamodb tells me that my key is duplicated?

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly encourage you to add some logging to ensure you have no duplicates in a batch. When you get an exception simply log the batch for inspection.

Items must have the same primary key to be duplicates.